# Reading and Parsing XML in vb .NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<HorseRacingCard>
  <Meeting status="Dormant" id="51894" country="South Africa" course="Vaal" date="20121101">
    <DrawAdvantage>Outside draws hold an advantage on the straight course.</DrawAdvantage>
    <AdvancedGoing>Good</AdvancedGoing>
    <Race trifecta="No" id="433065" date="20121101" time="1010+0000" raceType="Flat" trackType="Turf" handicap="No" class="" showcase="No" maxRunners="16">
      <Title>Save The Date Sansui Summer Cup 1 December Maiden Plate</Title>
      <AddedMoney currency="ZAR" amount="74996"/>
      <PenaltyValue currency="ZAR" amount="51622"/>
      <Prizes currency="ZAR">
        <Prize position="1" amount="51622"/>
        <Prize position="2" amount="14833"/>
        <Prize position="3" amount="7410"/>
      </Prizes>
      <Eligibility type="3YO plus"/>
      <Distance units="yards" value="1094" text="0m 4f 214y"/>
      <LastWinner year="2011" noRace="No corresponding race"/>
      <Horse id="1515186" name="Magic Of Rome" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="1"/>
    <Drawn stall="8"/>
    <FormFigures figures="598793" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="21"/>
    <Age years="5"/>
    <Weight text="9 6" units="pounds" value="132"/>
    <Trainer id="41207" name="Chris Erasmus" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Messrs Werner Kuhn &amp; Tjaart Strydom"/>
    <Jockey id="82671" name="J V'd Merwe"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101001.png" description="Yellow, purple epaulettes, armbands and cuffs, checked cap"/>
    <Tackle type="Blinkers" count="21"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="g"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Caesour" bred="USA" yearBorn="1990"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Magic Filly" bred="AUS"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Bletchley Park" bred="IRE" yearBorn="1989"/>
    <FoalDate date="20070815"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="14" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1632709" name="Enblazoned Star" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="2"/>
    <Drawn stall="9"/>
    <FormFigures figures="306740" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="51"/>
    <Age years="4"/>
    <Weight text="9 6" units="pounds" value="132"/>
    <Trainer id="41348" name="Leon Erasmus" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Mr L J &amp; Mrs M J Erasmus"/>
    <Jockey id="1144567" name="Wesley Marwing"><Allowance units="pounds" value="9"/></Jockey>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101002.png" description="Red, blue epaulettes and sleeves, red cap"/>
    <Tackle type="Blinkers" count="14"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="g"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Bezrin" bred="USA" yearBorn="1999"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Starbright" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1995"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Fluorescent Light" bred="USA"/>
    <FoalDate date="20080926"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="14" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1736936" name="Mboweni" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="3"/>
    <Drawn stall="14"/>
    <FormFigures figures="742234" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="21"/>
    <RaceHistoryStat type="BeatenFavourite" value="2"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="41348" name="Leon Erasmus" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Mr F D A Menezes"/>
    <Jockey id="21795" name="G Lerena"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101003.png" description="White, black and orange striped sleeves, orange cap"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="c"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Lecture" bred="USA" yearBorn="1996"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Ad Valorem" bred="SAF" yearBorn="2000"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Caesour" bred="USA" yearBorn="1990"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090907"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="3" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1774005" name="Make My Majesty" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="4"/>
    <Drawn stall="4"/>
    <FormFigures figures="878755" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="5"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="45437" name="Romeo Francis"/>
    <Owner name="Mr R Francis"/>
    <Jockey id="60482" name="Derreck David"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101004.png" description="Red, black chevrons and sleeves, red armbands and cap"/>
    <Tackle type="Blinkers" count="5"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="c"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="The Sheik" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1996"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Mamzelle Magique" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1999"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Badger Land" bred="USA"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091102"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="14" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1806596" name="All The Ones" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="5"/>
    <Drawn stall="12"/>
    <FormFigures figures="54" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="5"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="41151" name="Paul Matchett"/>
    <Owner name="Messrs P J Magee &amp; J J Van Niekerk"/>
    <Jockey id="28125" name="R Simons"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101005.png" description="Red, silver stars"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="g"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Carpocrates" bred="USA" yearBorn="2003"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Kal Sufi" bred="SAF"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Al Mufti" bred="USA" yearBorn="1985"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091111"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="4" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819715" name="Dis'llbetheday" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="6"/>
    <Drawn stall="7"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="41149" name="Roy Magner"/>
    <Owner name="Mr &amp; Mrs E Prinsloo &amp; Messes A T &amp; E T Joseph &amp; Me"/>
    <Jockey id="30057" name="G Wrogemann"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101006.png" description="Oyster grey, claret collar, cuffs and cap"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="g"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Daylami" bred="IRE" yearBorn="1994"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="World Premiere" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1996"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Model Man" bred="SAF"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091111"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819716" name="Inews" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="7"/>
    <Drawn stall="11"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="41207" name="Chris Erasmus" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Messrs Werner Kuhn &amp; Tjaart Strydom"/>
    <Jockey id="22000" name="S Veale"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101007.png" description="Yellow, purple epaulettes, armbands and cuffs, checked cap"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="c"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Winter Romance" bred="UK" yearBorn="1993"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Readallaboutit" bred="SAF"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Gallic League" bred="IRE"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090915"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819717" name="Magic Lad" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="8"/>
    <Drawn stall="10"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="100130" name="Stanley M Ferreira"/>
    <Owner name="Mr M J Nunes"/>
    <Jockey id="28344" name="Menno Malherbe"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101008.png" description="Black, white maltese cross, black and white striped sleeves and cap"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="c"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Jallad" bred="USA" yearBorn="1988"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Magic Filly" bred="AUS"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Bletchley Park" bred="IRE" yearBorn="1989"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090921"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="10" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819718" name="Menacing" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="9"/>
    <Drawn stall="2"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="55813" name="Michael Nicholas Houdalakis" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Mr Colin Bird"/>
    <Jockey id="28018" name="C Maujean"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa101009.png" description="Black, red chevron, black sleeves, red cap"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="g"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Go Deputy" bred="USA" yearBorn="2000"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Fearsome" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1997"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Centenary" bred="USA"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090906"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="14" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>        
  </Horse>
    </Race>
    <Race trifecta="No" id="433066" date="20121101" time="1045+0000" raceType="Flat" trackType="Turf" handicap="No" class="" showcase="No" maxRunners="16">
      <Title>All To Come Maiden Plate (F &amp; M)</Title>
      <AddedMoney currency="ZAR" amount="74996"/>
      <PenaltyValue currency="ZAR" amount="51622"/>
      <Prizes currency="ZAR">
        <Prize position="1" amount="51622"/>
        <Prize position="2" amount="14833"/>
        <Prize position="3" amount="7410"/>
      </Prizes>
      <Eligibility type="3YO plus"/>
      <Distance units="yards" value="1312" text="0m 5f 212y"/>
      <LastWinner year="2011" noRace="No corresponding race"/>
      <Horse id="1702450" name="Festive Interlude" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="1"/>
    <Drawn stall="3"/>
    <FormFigures figures="272533" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="5"/>
    <Age years="4"/>
    <Weight text="9 6" units="pounds" value="132"/>
    <Trainer id="15533" name="D Gray St John"/>
    <Owner name="Mr St John D Gray"/>
    <Jockey id="21795" name="G Lerena"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104501.png" description="Green, white rings, quartered cap"/>
    <Tackle type="Blinkers" count="10"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Sarge" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1999"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Festive Ways" bred="SAF" yearBorn="2000"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Model Man" bred="SAF"/>
    <FoalDate date="20080920"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="5" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1682817" name="Snow Go" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="2"/>
    <Drawn stall="12"/>
    <FormFigures figures="789850" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="28"/>
    <Age years="4"/>
    <Weight text="9 6" units="pounds" value="132"/>
    <Trainer id="41198" name="Dominic Zaki"/>
    <Owner name="Messrs G, K &amp; M M Nassif &amp; Messrs A G Eaton, R Kay"/>
    <Jockey id="81293" name="Grant Van Niekerk"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104502.png" description="Red, red and grey checked sleeves, grey cap, red star"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Go Deputy" bred="USA" yearBorn="2000"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Frostbite" bred="SAF" yearBorn="2002"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Western Winter" bred="USA" yearBorn="1900"/>
    <FoalDate date="20081003"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="14" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1756220" name="Margot On Stage" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="3"/>
    <Drawn stall="8"/>
    <FormFigures figures="345342" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="16"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="41149" name="Roy Magner"/>
    <Owner name="Messers M Zackey, S Sheik &amp; D G Zackey"/>
    <Jockey id="28799" name="K Zechner"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104503.png" description="Black and turquoise halved vertically, turquoise sleeves, halved cap"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Stagelight" bred="IRE" yearBorn="2002"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Sweet Margot" bred="SAF" yearBorn="2003"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Saumarez" bred="UK" yearBorn="1987"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090920"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="7" denominator="4"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1736110" name="Where Eagles Dare" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="4"/>
    <Drawn stall="14"/>
    <FormFigures figures="5602" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="37"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="101933" name="Paul Peter" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Messrs G T Peter &amp; Joel Peter"/>
    <Jockey id="28071" name="Chad Little"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104504.png" description="Red and white checks, striped sleeves, white cap"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Silvano" bred="GER" yearBorn="1996"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Aerial Dancer" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1991"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Dancing Champ" bred="USA"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091025"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="5" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1796892" name="Always Camille" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="5"/>
    <Drawn stall="16"/>
    <FormFigures figures="9" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="37"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="46483" name="Barend Daniel Botes"/>
    <Owner name="Mr S J D Mynhardt"/>
    <Jockey id="28083" name="Francois Herholdt"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104505.png" description="White, pink diamond hoop, white sleeves, pink collar and cuffs, diamonds on cap, white peak"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Caesour" bred="USA" yearBorn="1990"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Truely Yours" bred="SAF"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Northern Guest" bred="USA" yearBorn="1977"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091022"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819719" name="Apple At Us" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="6"/>
    <Drawn stall="6"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="104350" name="Scott Kenny" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Messrs N S W Cullingworth, G D E Kahan, W McLean &amp;"/>
    <Jockey id="41571" name="Timothy Pretorius"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104506.png" description="Black, gold chevron, black sleeves, gold seams, black cap, gold diamond"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Eyeofthetiger" bred="BRZ" yearBorn="2002"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Apple At 'em" bred="SAF" yearBorn="2001"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Up And At 'em" bred="UK" yearBorn="1990"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090919"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819720" name="Brave Princess" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="7"/>
    <Drawn stall="1"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="100130" name="Stanley M Ferreira"/>
    <Owner name="Messrs S Rudd &amp; M J Nunes"/>
    <Jockey id="28344" name="Menno Malherbe"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104507.png" description="Red, pale blue v bib, red sleeves, pale blue cap"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Mogok" bred="USA"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Bravo Bamby" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1993"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Dolpour" bred="FR"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090818"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819721" name="Dying Thunder" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="8"/>
    <Drawn stall="2"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="43065" name="Wallace Tolmay"/>
    <Owner name="Mrs H E Truter"/>
    <Jockey id="28088" name="Fanie Chambers"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104508.png" description="Red, white crossed sashes, black sleeves, black and white checked cap"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Fort Boyard" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1999"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Wild Cat Strike" bred="SAF" yearBorn="2002"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Restructure" bred="IRE" yearBorn="1992"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091101"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1736913" name="Fine Victory" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="9"/>
    <Drawn stall="11"/>
    <FormFigures figures="6" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="205"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="61673" name="Grant Maroun"/>
    <Owner name="Mr &amp; Mrs Mark Aboud &amp; Mesdames L J Schouten, Y J V"/>
    <Jockey id="28377" name="M Yeni"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104509.png" description="Shocking pink, black diamonds, black collar and cuffs, shocking pink cap, black diamonds and peak"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Victory Moon" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1999"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Fine Image" bred="SAF" yearBorn="2000"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Jallad" bred="USA" yearBorn="1988"/>
    <FoalDate date="20090828"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1805775" name="Fortitude" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="10"/>
    <Drawn stall="9"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="55813" name="Michael Nicholas Houdalakis" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Stone Hill Stud (nom: Mr H C W Rix)"/>
    <Jockey id="28018" name="C Maujean"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104510.png" description="Lime green, black diamond, lime green sleeves and cap, black diamond"/>
    <Colour type="b"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Stronghold" bred="UK" yearBorn="2002"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Mininski" bred="SNL"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Ahonoora" bred="UK"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091010"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="3" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1819722" name="Idle Hour" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="11"/>
    <Drawn stall="4"/>
    <FormFigures figures="" type="FlatSix"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="55813" name="Michael Nicholas Houdalakis" nationality="SAF"/>
    <Owner name="Stone Hill Stud (nom: Mr H C W Rix)"/>
    <Jockey id="28069" name="Francois Naude"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104511.png" description="Lime green, black diamond, lime green sleeves and cap, black diamond"/>
    <Colour type="gr"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Imperial Stride" bred="UK" yearBorn="2001"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Time Of My Life" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1994"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Royal Messenger" bred="SAF"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091023"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="14" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>
  </Horse>
      <Horse id="1736926" name="Lady Jallad" bred="SAF">
    <Cloth number="12"/>
    <Drawn stall="5"/>
    <FormFigures figures="075" type="FlatSix"/>
    <LastRunDays type="Flat" days="5"/>
    <Age years="3"/>
    <Weight text="9 4" units="pounds" value="130"/>
    <Trainer id="61673" name="Grant Maroun"/>
    <Owner name="Mr G J Maroun"/>
    <Jockey id="28082" name="Marco V'Rensburg"/>
    <JockeyColours filename="20121101vaa104512.png" description="White, purple maltese cross and cap"/>
    <Colour type="ch"/>
    <Sex type="f"/>
    <Breeding type="Sire" name="Announce" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1997"/><Breeding type="Dam" name="Hey Miss Jallad" bred="SAF" yearBorn="1994"/><Breeding type="DamSire" name="Jallad" bred="USA" yearBorn="1988"/>
    <FoalDate date="20091014"/>
    <ForecastPrice>
      <Price numerator="20" denominator="1"/>
      </ForecastPrice>

  </Horse>
    </Race>
  </Meeting>
</HorseRacingCard>
```

Sorry for the long XML file, but it's what I'm working with :) - it actually contains more races and horses in each race than that, but I've shortened it down to just a few races - I was over the limit of posting restrictions. What is basically is, is a horse meeting, which contains it's races and the horses which ran in each race.

I'm used to working with and seperating .csv files and have secured that, but the way things are going it's looking like I'm going to have to begin reading XML files and updating the database accordingly. Anyway, I'm a beginner to XML and vb .NET as a whole (a few month experience) and should probably not be jumping into such a complicated XML file so early on - I'll post my code below, and if somebody could point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong (probably a lot) and possibly provide me with some code/tutorials that will help me tackle this XML file then it would be much appreciated.

What I'm looking to do is populate three different structures; Meeting, Race and Horse, with the corresponding information from the XML file. I can solve the database updating afterwards by myself, I believe (hopefully) :D

```
Public Sub ExtractionService(ByVal spfile As FileInfo)
        Dim strreader As New StreamReader(_sendpathname & spfile.Name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim xmlreader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(strreader)
        xmlreader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None

        Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument()
        xmldoc.Load(xmlreader)

        Dim xml_nodelist As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("/HorseRacingCard/Meeting/Race/Horse")

        Dim mStatus As String
        Dim mID As Integer
        Dim mCountry As String
        Dim mCourse As String
        Dim mDate As Integer
        Dim mDrawAdvantage As String
        Dim mAdvancedGoing As String


        For Each mxmlnode As XmlNode In xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Meeting")
            mStatus = mxmlnode.Attributes.ItemOf("status").InnerText
            mID = mxmlnode.Attributes.ItemOf("id").InnerText
            mCountry = mxmlnode.Attributes.ItemOf("country").InnerText
            mCourse = mxmlnode.Attributes.ItemOf("course").InnerText
            mDate = mxmlnode.Attributes.ItemOf("date").InnerText
            mDrawAdvantage = mxmlnode.SelectSingleNode("DrawAdvantage").InnerText
            mAdvancedGoing = mxmlnode.SelectSingleNode("AdvancedGoing").InnerText

            _meeting.meetingStatus = mStatus
            _meeting.meetingID = mID
            _meeting.country = mCountry
            _meeting.course = mCourse
            _meeting.meetingDate = mDate
            _meeting.drawAdvantage = mDrawAdvantage
            _meeting.advancedGoing = mAdvancedGoing
        Next

    End Sub
```

This code manages to populate my meeting structure succesfully, but I just can't figure out I would go about populating the Race and Horse structures :( - I've followed a few tutorials and cannot seem to get my head around it. I understand I'm probably taking the wrong route here, and that there is potentially so much more I need to add/change to this in order for it to function the way I wish. Once these additions and changes have been highlighted, I believe I can then research these areas, and use the code which you guys can hopefully provide me with, to try tackle this.

Again, all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use XPath with XmlDocument.SelectNodes(), I think that's easier to find nodes and loop in it, also the code is easy to read too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like these, you are generally best off having each class have its own parsing function.  Classes higher in the hierarchy can parse their own information and pass the elements for the contained classes to the respective methods.

Also I much prefer the API of and the extra syntax VB gives for the XLINQ classes (`XElement` and friends) over the `XmlDocument` classes, so I'll use them in my example.  The general principal does not change.

```vb
Class Meeting
    'properties, etc

    Public Shared Function Parse(element As XElement) As Meeting
        'argument error checking here

        Dim ret As New Meeting()

        ret.Status = element.@status
        ret.DrawAdvantage = element.<DrawAdvantage>.Value
        'other properties

        Dim parsedRaces = From re In element.<Race>
                          Select Race.Parse(re)
        For Each r In parsedRaces
            'add to meeting race collection
        Next

        Return ret
    End Function
End Class

Class Race
    'properties, etc

    Public Shared Function Parse(element As XElement) As Race
        'parse and return race data
    End Function
End Class
```

Typically, I will not put methods that directly open a file on the classes themselves.  Instead, whatever class determines the file name (form, window, view model, application) will be responsible for reading and writing the `XElement` to the file.  Sometimes I will even move the `Parse` (and associated `Save`) methods to a different class if there are multiple ways an object is being stored or there are other layering concerns.  In either case, I make the parse method create and return new instances of the class so I do not have to worry about partially mutated state if an exception is thrown.